# How to evaluate for each custom entity in OpenNLP?

Tags: java, nlp, text-mining, opennlp

I am working on a application where users can tag text and train it to a model at the same time.

For this I use OpenNLP (Named Entity Recognition) for Java and so far this works good.

Since the user can add custom tags, I use custom training data. The training works and I get a model.

Now I wan't to test this model by using the Evaluation API. I split my data in test and training data. The test data I use as stream for the evaluation. This works fine too and I get a global precision, recall and f-measure for the entire model.

What I wan't to achieve is this results for every entity separately.

For example:

```
Although she has always lived in <START:COUNTRY> France <END> , she speaks fluent <START:LANGUAGE> English <END> because her mother was <START:NATIONALITY> American <END> and her father was <START:NATIONALITY> Nigerian <END> .
```

Precision for COUNTRY, precision for LANGUAGE, precision for NATIONALITY

Is this possible with OpenNLP?

Please help, thanks!